# flutter does not show data from API

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, dio

When I try to pull data from the jsonplaceholder API and put it on the screen, I don't have any problems, but when I try to change the data in this link (https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 ) on the reqres.io site with the same codes, only by changing the API and model, the text no data appears on the screen. I'm getting it can you help me ?

## **My project with JsonPlaceHolder**

## ***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';

import 'service/api_service.dart';

void main() =\> runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'Material App',
home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text('Json Deneme'),
),
body: const Home(),
),
);
}
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({super.key});

@override
State\<Home\> createState() =\> \_HomeState();
}

class \_HomeState extends State\<Home\> {
List\<JsonModel\>? \_postItems;
bool \_isLoading = false;
String? \_errorMessage;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
loadData();
}

Future\<void\> loadData() async {
setState(() {
_isLoading = true;
_errorMessage = null;
});
try {
final postItems = await Api.fetchApi();
setState(() {
_postItems = postItems;
_isLoading = false;
});
} catch (e) {
setState(() {
_isLoading = false;
_errorMessage = 'Error fetching data: $e';
});
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (\_isLoading) {
return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
} else if (\_postItems == null || \_postItems!.isEmpty) {
return const Center(child: Text('No Data'));
} else {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: \_postItems!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(\_postItems!\[index\].name),
);
},
);
}
}
}`
```

## **api_service.dart**

```
`import 'dart:io';

import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class Api {
static Future<List<JsonModel>?> fetchApi() async {
final res = await Dio().get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
if (res.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
final data = res.data!;
if (data is List) {
return data.map((e) =\> JsonModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
}
}
return <JsonModel>[];
}
}
`
```

## **conclusion**

[conclusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osDOJ.png)

## My project with reqres.in

## **main.dart**

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';

import 'service/api_service.dart'; 

void main() =\> runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
title: 'Material App',
home: Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text('Json Deneme'),
),
body: const Home(),
),
);
}
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({super.key});

@override
State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
List<ReqresModel>? _postItems;
bool _isLoading = false;
String? _errorMessage;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
loadData();
}

Future<void> loadData() async {
setState(() {
_isLoading = true;
_errorMessage = null;
});
try {
final postItems = await Api.fetchApi();
setState(() {
_postItems = postItems;
_isLoading = false;
});
} catch (e) {
setState(() {
_isLoading = false;
_errorMessage = 'Error fetching data: $e';
}); 
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (_isLoading) {
return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
} else if (_postItems == null || _postItems!.isEmpty) { 
return const Center(child: Text('No Data'));
} else {
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: _postItems!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(\_postItems!\[index\].data\[index\].firstName),
);
},
);
}
}
}`
```

## **api_servise.dart**

```
`import 'dart:io';

 import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';
 import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

 class Api {
 static Future<List<ReqresModel>?> fetchApi() async {
 final res = await Dio().get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
 if (res.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
 final data = res.data!;
 if (data is List) {
 return data.map((e) => ReqresModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
 }
 }
 return <ReqresModel>[];
 }
 }`
```

## **conclusion**

[conclusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxfpA.png)

## **Thank you **

I sent the API using Postman, there was no problem, I don't think the problem was caused by the API, sorry for my bad English

Comment: try using FutureBuilder for future method

Comment: I tried but the result did not change

Comment: try to print/debug to see data on console

Comment: i tried but i don't get an error message in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `api_service.dart` for `reqres.in` project with following code.
First api which returns `List` directly, but second api which return `Json` which has `data` as `List`

***Edited***

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';

import 'service/api_service.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Json Deneme'),
        ),
        body: const Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<ReqresModel>? _postItems;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String? _errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  Future<void> loadData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
      _errorMessage = null;
    });
    try {
      final postItems = await Api.fetchApi();
      setState(() {
        _postItems = postItems;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
        _errorMessage = 'Error fetching data: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (_postItems == null || _postItems!.isEmpty) {
      return const Center(child: Text('No Data'));
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _postItems!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_postItems![index].firstName),//Updated here
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**api_service.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:my_app/models/json_model.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class Api {
  static Future<List<ReqresModel>?> fetchApi() async {
    final res = await Dio().get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
    if (res.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      final data = res.data!['data'];//Updated here
      if (data is List) {
        return data.map((e) => ReqresModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
      }
    }
    return <ReqresModel>[];
  }
}
```

**ReqresModel** - should be updated

```
//Updated here
class ReqresModel {
  int? id;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? avatar;

  ReqresModel(
      {this.id, this.email, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.avatar});

  ReqresModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    avatar = json['avatar'];
  }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, it still writes not data on the screen

Comment: I updated the answer there are changes in three files

Comment: Search by `//Updated here` to know the changes

Comment: thank you so much for everything i have been working on this for days

Comment: can i ask a question, did you create the model file yourself or did you use a converter?

Comment: https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/